# Get default grid back to sheet ExcelPackage

Tags: c#, excelpackage

I created an Excel sheet, using *ExcelPackage*.
I gave some cells a different color, for clearing up the sheet.

**Problem:**

The default grid gets removed as in picture below:
[image: Custom colored fields]

First Column has the default grid overlay, the other ones don't have this grid.
I tried re-enabling that grid and tried using the following code:

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.None);
```

Above code gave me same as picture.

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
```

Above code gave me a thicker line than the default.

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Medium);
```

Above code gave me a even thicker line than the default.

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Hair);
```

Above code gave me a dotted line.

**Question:**

Can someone help me with this, where can I find the correct syntax, since the community on `ExcelPackage` isn't that big and I can't find it on their *CodePlex* page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting Fill colours within the cells the default grid is removed, this functionality can also be seen within Excel by simply setting a background color of a cell. So you will have to manually add the borders to display them.

This will mean you will most likely have to come up with a new border style for the entire grid. Example :

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.Thin);
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
```

Alternatively if you have a need to remove cell backgrounds you can do the following :

```
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Border.Bottom.BorderAround(ExcelBorderStyle.None);
worksheet.Cells[row, col].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.None;
```

This will set the default background and border styles for the cell.

Hope this helps.